# Gradle speed up - using module approach

Tags: gradle

A lot of articles describe how you can speed up gradle build by splitting project into modules.

I don’t understand why. If you structure your code in a modular way with clean dependencies, the compiler should recognize what code changed and build in an optimal way. (Implement everything in same module)

To me, modularization is just a way to force clean dependencies, and does not speed up build by itself, am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With up-to-date checking and build caching gradle only builds sourcesets that have changed or have dependencies that changed. So if you make a change in an application that has chunks of it's code in libs/modules, they don't need to be rebuild/re-tested. This can save a lot of build time.

Comment: Didn’t understand that. So if code is not in module they will be rebuilt everytime? I still don’t understand why module would make a difference

Comment: gradle will compile a module into a jar, if the jar (or rather the input for the jar) did not change, it will re-use it in stead of rebuilding it. It will then also skip running the tests.
If all code is in 1 module, 1 change will always mean all code needs to be rebuild and tested. If its split among modules only the changed module (and the ones that depend on it) need to rebuild